# Stop processing message after match in Errbot

Tags: errbot

how I can stop processing message after match?
For example something like this:

```
    @re_botcmd(pattern=r"(.*)(damn|fuck|stupid)(.*)$", flags=re.IGNORECASE,matchall=True)
    def be_nice(self, msg, match):
        yield "Could you be more nice (((?"
        stop_processing_msg(msg)
```

Also is there a way to orginize matching, so it can be done in particular order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this specific feature I would use a command filter: http://errbot.io/en/latest/errbot.html#errbot.cmdfilter

Send a message directly to the user and you have the opportunity here to block the processing.

As for the order of interpretation, we don't have a complete solution yet but we have:

- the config parameter PLUGINS_CALLBACK_ORDER in the config file which works for the callbacks.
- an alternative might be a flow depending on which order you want to enforce: http://errbot.io/en/latest/user_guide/flow_development/advanced.html#making-a-step-execute-automatically

Comment: Thanks, this helped.